# In a Swift program, why is my Eraser tool pixelated?

Tags: ios, swift3, core-graphics, eraser

There are numerous questions about creating an eraser tool in CoreGraphics. I cannot find one that matches "pixelated".

Here's the situation. I'm playing with a simple drawing project. The pen tools work fine. The eraser tool is horribly pixelated. Here's a screen shot of what I mean:

[image]

Here's the drawing code I'm using:

```
 //  DrawingView
//  
//
//  Created by David DelMonte on 12/9/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 David DelMonte. All rights reserved.
//


import UIKit


public protocol DrawingViewDelegate {
    func didBeginDrawing(view: DrawingView)
    func isDrawing(view: DrawingView)
    func didFinishDrawing(view: DrawingView)
    func didCancelDrawing(view: DrawingView)
}



open class DrawingView: UIView {
    
    //initial settings
    public var lineColor: UIColor = UIColor.black
    public var lineWidth: CGFloat = 10.0
    public var lineOpacity: CGFloat = 1.0
    //public var lineBlendMode: CGBlendMode = .normal
    
    //used for zoom actions
    public var drawingEnabled: Bool = true
    
    public var delegate: DrawingViewDelegate?
    
    private var currentPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()
    private var previousPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()
    private var previousPreviousPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()
    
    private var pathArray: [Line] = []
    private var redoArray: [Line] = []
    
    var toolType: Int = 0
    
    let π = CGFloat(M_PI)
    private let forceSensitivity: CGFloat = 4.0
    
    
    private struct Line {
        var path: CGMutablePath
        var color: UIColor
        var width: CGFloat
        var opacity: CGFloat
        //var blendMode: CGBlendMode
        
        init(path : CGMutablePath, color: UIColor, width: CGFloat, opacity: CGFloat) {
            self.path = path
            self.color = color
            self.width = width
            self.opacity = opacity
            //self.blendMode = blendMode
        }
    }
    
    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    
    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context : CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        
        for line in pathArray {
            context.setLineWidth(line.width)
            context.setAlpha(line.opacity)
            context.setLineCap(.round)
            
            switch toolType {
            case 0: //pen
                
                context.setStrokeColor(line.color.cgColor)
                context.addPath(line.path)
                context.setBlendMode(.normal)
                
                break
                
            case 1: //eraser
                
                context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
                context.addPath(line.path)
                context.setBlendMode(.clear)
                
                break
                
            case 3: //multiply
                
                context.setStrokeColor(line.color.cgColor)
                context.addPath(line.path)
                context.setBlendMode(.multiply)
                
                break
                
            default:
                break
            }
            
            context.beginTransparencyLayer(auxiliaryInfo: nil)
            context.strokePath()
            context.endTransparencyLayer()
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard drawingEnabled == true else {
            return
        }
        
        self.delegate?.didBeginDrawing(view: self)
        if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {
            //setTouchPoints(touch, view: self)
            previousPoint = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
            previousPreviousPoint = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
            currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
            
            let newLine = Line(path: CGMutablePath(), color: self.lineColor, width: self.lineWidth, opacity: self.lineOpacity)
            newLine.path.addPath(createNewPath())
            pathArray.append(newLine)
        }
    }
    
    override open func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard drawingEnabled == true else {
            return
        }
        
        self.delegate?.isDrawing(view: self)
        if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {
            //updateTouchPoints(touch, view: self)
            previousPreviousPoint = previousPoint
            previousPoint = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
            currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
            
            let newLine = createNewPath()
            if let currentPath = pathArray.last {
                currentPath.path.addPath(newLine)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override open func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard drawingEnabled == true else {
            return
        }
        
        
    }
    
    override open func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard drawingEnabled == true else {
            return
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    public func canUndo() -> Bool {
        if pathArray.count > 0 {return true}
        return false
    }
    
    public func canRedo() -> Bool {
        return redoArray.count > 0
    }

    
    public func undo() {
        if pathArray.count > 0 {
            
            redoArray.append(pathArray.last!)
            pathArray.removeLast()
        }
        
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    public func redo() {
        if redoArray.count > 0 {
            pathArray.append(redoArray.last!)
            redoArray.removeLast()
        }
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    public func clearCanvas() {
        pathArray = []
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }



    private func createNewPath() -> CGMutablePath {
        //print(#function)
        let midPoints = getMidPoints()
        let subPath = createSubPath(midPoints.0, mid2: midPoints.1)
        let newPath = addSubPathToPath(subPath)
        return newPath
    }
    
    private func calculateMidPoint(_ p1 : CGPoint, p2 : CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        //print(#function)
        return CGPoint(x: (p1.x + p2.x) * 0.5, y: (p1.y + p2.y) * 0.5);
    }
    
    private func getMidPoints() -> (CGPoint,  CGPoint) {
        //print(#function)
        let mid1 : CGPoint = calculateMidPoint(previousPoint, p2: previousPreviousPoint)
        let mid2 : CGPoint = calculateMidPoint(currentPoint, p2: previousPoint)
        return (mid1, mid2)
    }
    
    private func createSubPath(_ mid1: CGPoint, mid2: CGPoint) -> CGMutablePath {
        //print(#function)
        let subpath : CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
        subpath.move(to: CGPoint(x: mid1.x, y: mid1.y))
        subpath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: mid2.x, y: mid2.y), control: CGPoint(x: previousPoint.x, y: previousPoint.y))
        return subpath
    }
    
    private func addSubPathToPath(_ subpath: CGMutablePath) -> CGMutablePath {
        //print(#function)
        let bounds : CGRect = subpath.boundingBox
        
        let drawBox : CGRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: -0.54 * lineWidth, dy: -0.54 * lineWidth)
        self.setNeedsDisplay(drawBox)
        return subpath
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I notice that each eraser touch is square. Please see the second image to show in more detail:

[image]

I then rewrote some code as suggested by Pranal Jaiswal:

```
override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        print(#function)
        let context : CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        
        if isEraserSelected {
            for line in undoArray {
                //context.beginTransparencyLayer(auxiliaryInfo: nil)
                context.setLineWidth(line.width)
                context.addPath(line.path)
                context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
                context.setBlendMode(.clear)
                context.setAlpha(line.opacity)
                context.setLineCap(.round)
                context.strokePath()

            }
        } else {
            for line in undoArray {
                context.setLineWidth(line.width)
                context.setLineCap(.round)
                context.addPath(line.path)
                context.setStrokeColor(line.color.cgColor)
                context.setBlendMode(.normal)
                context.setAlpha(line.opacity)
                context.strokePath()
            }
            
        }
    }
```

I'm still getting the same result. What can I try next?

Comment: Can u post entire code of ur drawing class like I did in my answer? I can better figure out the issue that way...

Comment: Thanks for looking again. I've added my full drawing class now. Please note, I am using arrays to store points for use by my undo/redo functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't exactly look at your code. But I had done something similar in Swift 2.3 a while ago (I do understand you are looking at Swift 3 but right now this is version that I have).

Here is how the drawing class works looks like.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class PRSignatureView: UIView

{

var drawingColor:CGColorRef = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor //Col
var drawingThickness:CGFloat = 0.5
var drawingAlpha:CGFloat = 1.0

var isEraserSelected: Bool

private var currentPoint:CGPoint?
private var previousPoint1:CGPoint?
private var previousPoint2:CGPoint?

private var path:CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()

var image:UIImage?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    //self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.isEraserSelected = false
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
{
    self.isEraserSelected ? self.eraseMode() : self.drawingMode()
}

private func drawingMode()
{
    if (self.image != nil)
    {
        self.image!.drawInRect(self.bounds)
    }
    let context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    CGContextAddPath(context, path)
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.drawingThickness)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, drawingColor)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, self.drawingAlpha)
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

private func eraseMode()
{
    if (self.image != nil)
    {
        self.image!.drawInRect(self.bounds)
    }
    let context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.drawingThickness)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Clear)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)
}




private func midPoint (p1:CGPoint, p2:CGPoint)->CGPoint
{
    return CGPointMake((p1.x + p2.x) * 0.5, (p1.y + p2.y) * 0.5)
}

private func finishDrawing()
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0.0);
    drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}

func clearSignature()
{
    path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    self.image = nil;
    self.setNeedsDisplay();
}

// MARK: - Touch Delegates
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    let touch = touches.first!
    previousPoint1 = touch.previousLocationInView(self)
    currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1
    previousPoint1 = touch.previousLocationInView(self)
    currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
    
    let mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint2!, p2: previousPoint1!)
    let mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint!, p2: previousPoint1!)
    
    let subpath:CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(subpath, nil, mid1.x, mid1.y)
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(subpath, nil, previousPoint1!.x, previousPoint1!.y, mid2.x, mid2.y)
    CGPathAddPath(path, nil, subpath);
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
    self.finishDrawing()
}
override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.touchesMoved(touches!, withEvent: event)
    self.finishDrawing()
}

}
```

[Source Code for test app I created using the above code](https://bitbucket.org/Pranav_Jaiswal/stackoverflowanswers/src)

**Edit: Converting few lines code to swift 3 as requested**

```
subpath.move(to: CGPoint(x: mid1.x, y: mid1.y))
subpath.addQuadCurve(to:CGPoint(x: mid2.x, y: mid2.y) , control: CGPoint(x: previousPoint1!.x, y: previousPoint1!.y))
path.addPath(subpath)
```

**Edit: In response to the updated Question**

Here is the updated Drawing Class that must solve the issue for sure. [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5nqEBSJjCriTU5oRXd5c2hRV28/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-8ZE92CSD3j7xxB5jGvgj2w](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5nqEBSJjCriTU5oRXd5c2hRV28/view?usp=sharing)

Issues addressed:

1. `Line` Struct did not hold the tool type associated. Whenever `setNeedsDislpay()` is called you redraw all the objects in `pathArray` and all Objects were getting redrawn with the current selected tool. I have added a new variable `associatedTool` to address the issue.
2. Use of function `beginTransparencyLayer` will set the blend mode to `kCGBlendModeNormal`. As this was common for all cases related to tooltype this was causing the mode to be set to normal.  I have removed these two lines

> //context.beginTransparencyLayer(auxiliaryInfo: nil)
>
> //context.endTransparencyLayer()

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out asap. I appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: I'm trying to convert your drawing code to Swift3.. I'm hung up with the touchesMoved function. Specifically:  CGPathMoveToPoint(subpath, nil, mid1.x, mid1.y). They don't compile.. Any ideas? Thanks again
 
 
        CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(subpath, nil, previousPoint1!.x, previousPoint1!.y, mid2.x, mid2.y)\n
        CGPathAddPath(path, nil, subpath);\n

Comment: Please check edited answer. Should work, didn't test it though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this it has no error while erasing and it can be us for drawing erasing and clearing your screen. you can even increase or decrease ur size of the pencil and eraser. also u may change color accordingly.

hope this is helpfull for u.....

import UIKit

```
class DrawingView: UIView {

var lineColor:CGColor = UIColor.black.cgColor 
var lineWidth:CGFloat = 5
var drawingAlpha:CGFloat = 1.0

var isEraserSelected: Bool

private var currentPoint:CGPoint?
private var previousPoint1:CGPoint?
private var previousPoint2:CGPoint?

private var path:CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()

var image:UIImage?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    //self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.isEraserSelected = false
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
{
    self.isEraserSelected ? self.eraseMode() : self.drawingMode()
}

private func drawingMode()
{
    if (self.image != nil)
    {
        self.image!.draw(in: self.bounds)
    }
    let context:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.addPath(path)
    context.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context.setLineWidth(self.lineWidth)
    context.setStrokeColor(lineColor)
    context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    context.setAlpha(self.drawingAlpha)
    context.strokePath();
}

private func eraseMode()
{
    if (self.image != nil)
    {
        self.image!.draw(in: self.bounds)
    }
    let context:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.saveGState()
    context.addPath(path);
    context.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context.setLineWidth(self.lineWidth)
    context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.clear)
    context.strokePath()
    context.restoreGState()
}

private func midPoint (p1:CGPoint, p2:CGPoint)->CGPoint
{
    return CGPoint(x: (p1.x + p2.x) * 0.5, y: (p1.y + p2.y) * 0.5);
}

private func finishDrawing()
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0.0);
    drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}

func clearSignature()
{
    path = CGMutablePath()
    self.image = nil;
    self.setNeedsDisplay();
}

// MARK: - Touch Delegates
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    path = CGMutablePath()
    let touch = touches.first!
    previousPoint1 = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
    currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1
    previousPoint1 = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
    currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)

    let mid1 = midPoint(p1: previousPoint2!, p2: previousPoint1!)
    let mid2 = midPoint(p1: currentPoint!, p2: previousPoint1!)

    let subpath:CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
    subpath.move(to: CGPoint(x: mid1.x, y: mid1.y), transform: .identity)
    subpath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: mid2.x, y: mid2.y), control: CGPoint(x: (previousPoint1?.x)!, y: (previousPoint1?.y)!))
    path.addPath(subpath, transform: .identity)

    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    self.finishDrawing()
}
override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>?, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.touchesMoved(touches!, with: event)
    self.finishDrawing()
}
}
```

Comment: to be really helpful you should not only post code but also some explanations about what you did/why you did it etc.